# Xamarin binding library: InputJar package does not exist error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I have created a binding library in Xamarin with a .jar file. If I give the option as `EmbeddedJar` the project was compiling and running properly. But if I change it to `InputJar` then I am getting compile time error:

```
error:package come.abc.util does not exist com.abc.util.IListener.
```

I need to use `InputJar` because of some licencing issue. Please help.

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Android are you using? : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42091

Comment: I am using Xamarin version 7.3.1.2

Comment: Refering to [`Creating the Bindings Library`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/#Creating_the_Bindings_Library): If you want to keep the .JAR separate from the bindings library, you can use the `InputJar` option; however, you must ensure that the .JAR file is available on the device that runs your app.

Comment: I have got the same problem but sadly no solution. The problem seems to be related to interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this! At least in my case I had success.

You have to change the Android Options - Linking to "Sdk and User Assemblies" you find that one in the properties of your application.

After setting this option, my build went through and everything worked fine.